# Add products to another category programatically

Tags: magento-1.9, category-products

I have pulled the product set I need in with my collection, how do I add these products to another category whilst also being in the ones they are?

Here is my code so far:

```
    //Getting products that are need to go on sale page and have a special price
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->getCollection();
$collection ->addFieldToFilter('sale_exempt',1);
$collection ->addAttributeToFilter(
    array(
        array('attribute' => 'special_price', 'is'=>new Zend_Db_Expr('not null'))
    ));

var_dump($collection->getData());

$new_categoryId = 9;

foreach ($collection as $_product) {



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

```
    //Getting products that are need to go on sale page and have a special price
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->getCollection();
$collection ->addFieldToFilter('sale_exempt',1);
$collection ->addAttributeToFilter(
    array(
        array('attribute' => 'special_price', 'is'=>new Zend_Db_Expr('not null'))
    ));

$new_categoryId = array(9);

foreach ($collection as $_product) {

    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());
    $product->setCategoryIds($new_categoryId);
    $product->save();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's giving me this: Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 3 passed to Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Abstract::_canUpdateAttribute() must be of the type array, null given

Comment: @Tom: In a similar situation I had to write `Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID)` to fix this problem.